Spring Boot Web Socket Redirect
Hello i have a problem with redirect in my spring boot apps, i have user service which is custom gateway with feign clients to redirect, and core service which is connected to the database and have endpoint with websocket, core is hidden in web, only inside docker compose network u can connect to him, he dont expose any port, so now i make in user controller like this
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chat-websocket")
public class ChatWebSocketController {

    @Value("${com.nvt.core.api.url}")
    private String coreApiUrl;

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleWebSocket(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        //HOW TO REDIRECT WITH HANDSHAKE?
    }
}

and now i don't know how to redirect to make hanshake with fronent and core, because when i do response.redirect() etc. i get errror stomp.service.ts:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4205/proxy/chat-websocket/535/kgorcmtp/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
